# Moving objects from HTML page to jsp in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I am working on a project, and I need to access the data in the model class object in my jsp. My project is kind of big, so I'll post a problem that's similar and simpler.

Say there is a bank account with money in USD and I have to display in Indian rupees (1 USD = 70 rupees).

Account class:

```
public class Account 
{

    private String userName;
    private int balance;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public int getBalance(){return balance;}

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }}
```

Servlet class:

```
public class HomeController {

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String user(@Validated String user, Model model) {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested");
        Account account = new Bank();
        account.setUserName(user);
        //
        //       
        //  Some way to figure how much money there is in the user's account. For our purposes, say $5.
        //
        //
        account.setBalance(5);
        model.addAttribute("account",account);
        return "user";
    }
}
```

JSP:

user.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>User Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Hi ${account.getUserName()}</h3>
<% 
    int balance = ${account.getBalance()};
    balance = balance*70;
    out.println(" Balance is "+balance+" rupees");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, with the line:

```
int balance = ${account.getBalance()};
```

This line is wrong, but this is what I want to achieve. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated `user.jsp` is :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@ page import="com.example.Account" %>  
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>User Home Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h3>Hi ${account.userName}</h3>
   <% 
    Account account = (Account) request.getAttribute("account");
    int balance = account.getBalance() * 70;
    out.println(" Balance is "+balance+" rupees");
   %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Now when I try it, there is no "request.getAttribute("account")". The function does not exist in response

Comment: But sir, whenever I use the object, the page goes blank and does not show anything, but for the css part.

Comment: @Shanky301 I have updated my answer. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks but I want it within out.println(), in the format in my question. Basically, I want to access it as an object in jsp. Is that possible?

Comment: @Shanky301 Ok !! But this was an easy way.

Comment: Maybe here. But in the actual scenario, I badly need this sir.

Comment: Thanks sir. Got it now

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note here is, you can use property name directly instead of getters.

```
${account.userName}
```

And use JSTL for expression language enabled can perform multiplication like below.

`<c:set var="result" value="${balance * 70}"/>`

Comment: But I need it as an object in jsp

Comment: account is an object only thats why we are retrieving username from it